# Dropbox Core API for Swift:Cannot initialize DBSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dropbox-api

I was following the link below in order to use the Dropbox Core API in my iOS application: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios

However, this is all written in Objective C. I have gotten it so that I have imported the DropboxSDK into my project but I can't seem to find the Swift equivalent code of beginning the authorization process. I have tried  looking at all of the given functions in DBSession and DBSessionDelegate that look similar to those in the example tutorial above but I haven't had any luck. Any ideas how to do this? The following is the code in Objective C that I am trying to translate into Swift.

```
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
      initWithAppKey:@"INSERT_APP_KEY"
      appSecret:@"INSERT_APP_SECRET"
      root:INSERT_ACCESS_TYPE]; // either kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
```

Specifically, I can't seem to find any function to allow me to initialize my application key app secret, or root. If anyone could help me out, that'd be great! Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything that looks like DBSession(appKey:String, appSecret:String, root:)

Comment: I've looked but there doesn't seem to be any function that is similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

`let session = DBSession(appKey:"...", appSecret:"...", root:...);` works in my testing.

You may want to read https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/109/swift-apps-with-dropbox for the basics of using Dropbox SDKs in Swift. (That blog post doesn't deal specifically with the Core SDK, but the steps there still apply.)